# Forming a Stack Bar chart/ Grid with Color Intensity varying on Value

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, rgraph

I am Trying to make a grid look like stacked bar chart. The various sections of the Bar represent the App category and x-axis plots the bar on their price class. I want the color intensity of the section of the bar to change with the number of Apps in the category. I tried using ggplot2 geom_bar but am not able to figure out as to how can I plot categories on Y-axis. My data looks like this:

```
Category    No.Apps Price
Utilities   400     0
Utilities   300     1-10
Utilities   500     11-20
Utilities   200     21-30
Games       1000    0
Games       900     1-10
Games       400     11-20
Games       100     21-30
Productivity 300    0
Productivity 100    1-10
Productivity 50     11-20
Productivity 80     21-30
```

I want my graph to look somewhat like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEn2g.png

with categories on y-axis and price-class on x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

#making some fake data and putting it into a data.frame
price <- rnorm(n = 10000,mean = 5,sd = 2)
app <- sample(x = LETTERS[1:10],size = 10000,replace = T)
df <- data.frame(price,app)
head(df)

#now the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=price,y=app))+
  geom_bin2d()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to come close to your graphic, although the colors are different.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Price,y=Category, fill=No.Apps)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  coord_fixed()
```

Notes:

1. Used `geom_tile(...)` to make the blocks.
2. Used `rev(heat.colors(10))` to create the color palette (reds for high values, pale yellow for low values).
3. Used `coord_fixed(...)` so the blocks are square (sets aspect ration to 1:1).
4. Used `expand=c(0,0)` so the blocks fill the whole plotting area.